# Refresh all div from a class

Tags: jquery, ajax, reload

How can I refresh all div based on their class name ?
I did this but it's not work

```
setInterval(function()
{

$('.myclass').each(function () {
    $(this.id).load(location.href+" this.id>*","");
});
}, 10000);
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "refresh"? What do you want to achieve?

Comment: This is dynamic data, I want to reload the data from the serveur every 10 sec

Answer (score 2):

`$(this.id).load(...` creates an invalid selector without using a `#` prefix but all you really need is `$(this).load(...` since you already have a reference to that element

Then you have a syntax error adding the id to end of url also

---

You would probably be better off just making one request and parsing the response yourself. This would be more efficient than making numerous requests for the exact same resource

```
setInterval(function(){
   $.get(location.href, function(data){
      // loop through the new elements
      $(data).find('.myclass').each(function(){
          const id = this.id, 
                content = $(this).html();
          // insert into existing element with same id
          $('#' + id).html(content);          
       });
   });

},10000)
```